# Ways to determine the date of last Android update

Tags: android, updates, android-update-sdk

Is there a way of programmatically determine the date of last Android OS update?

Comment: What you are looking for is probably the `TIME` Constant in the `Build` class. However that refers to the time of the release of the current OS build and not the install time of the update.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to know the date of the last Android update rather than the time of the Android build. Are there any specific APIs to check the date of last system update? If not, are there any system files that will definitely be updated to the current date upon system update? Perhaps I could check on those.

Comment: I can confirm that the BUILD.TIME output is the build time of the release and not the install time on one specific device. We have tested this on two seperate devices with the same build number and see exactly matching timestamps to the second.